# Find of two arithmetic progressions meet

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I was working a problem to find if two AP meet or not and came across the below post 
[Formula to find if two AP meet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656120/formula-to-find-the-first-intersection-of-two-arithmetic-progressions)

and in that the formula given by user is

$$A_n=A_1+(n−1)d$$

$$B_m=B_1+(m−1)D$$

and if $A_n=B_m$ then they meet. But somehow it failed for my case of $A_1=14,d=4 B_1=98,D=2$.
Could you please tell me where i went wrong or the formula was wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE.  By definition, the formula is right.  In your failure case, what are the values of $n$ for $A_n$ and $m$ for $B_m$ that you tried using?

Comment: so as per the explanation given by user i got n as 2 and m as 1.

Comment: Thanks for providing those 2 values.  Based on your provided values, the $2$ arithmetic progressions don't meet at that point, as you determined yourself.

Comment: as per the formula they dont but the actual answer is they do meet and i am trying to figure out where did i go wrong

Comment: they both meet at 162.

Comment: did you mean $d=4, B_1=98$?

Comment: If so, then $A_n=14,18,22,26,\cdots$ and $B_m=98,100,102,104,\cdots$, hence the two series will "meet" $98, 102, 106, \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many variables involved to make that solution useful. Instead of looking at his results, I think it would be better to apply his method of solution to your particular problem.

\begin{align}
   14 + 4(m-1) &= 98 + 2(n-1) \\
   4m + 10 &= 2n + 96 \\
   2m + 5 &= n + 48 \\
   2m - n &= 43
\end{align}

In order for there to be a solution, we must have $\gcd(2, -1) \mid 43$. Which is true.

A solution would be $(m,n)=(22,1)$.

So, the general solution is therefore
$(m,n)=(22+t, 1+2t)$ for all integers $t \ge 0$.

We compute

$$14+4(22+t-1) = 98 + 4t$$
$$98 + 2(1+2t-1) = 98 + 4t$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameters provided, the expressions for $A_n$ and $B_m$ may be written as
$$A_n=4n+10=14, 18, 22, 26, \cdots\;\;\;\\
B_m=2m+96=98, 100, 102, 104, \cdots$$
hence the two series will "meet" at many points, e.g., $98, 102, 106, \cdots$
.

If "meeting" is taken to mean that $m=n$, i.e. where $A_n=B_n$, then this can be solved as two simultaneous equations,$y=4x+10$ and $y=2x+96$, giving $x=43$, hence the solution is $$A_n=B_n=182$$ where $n=43$.

Answer (score 0):

The $2$ sequences meet, but with $n$ being $22$, not $2$, for $m$ being $1$, with them meeting at $98$, as can be easily confirmed by plugging the values into the equations:
$$14 + \left(22 - 1\right)4 = 14 + \left(21\right)4 = 14 + 84 = 98$$
$$98 + \left(1 - 1\right)2 = 98 + 0 = 98$$
Note to determine $n$ and $m$, subtracting the second general formula from the first general one provided in the question gives:
$$84 = \left(n - 1\right)4 - \left(m - 1\right)2$$
$$84 = 4n - 4 - 2m + 2$$
$$86 = 4n - 2m$$
$$43 = 2n - m$$
Since both $m$ and $n$ must be $\geq 1$, so this limits what there values can be.  As $43$ is odd and $2n$ is even, the values of $m$ must all be odd.  The smallest odd value is $1$, with this giving $2n = 43 + 1 = 44$, so $n = 22$.

For each increase in $n$, the right side increases by $2$, so $m$ must increase by $2$ (as it is being subtracted) to compensate to keep it an equation. Thus, the sets of $\left(n,m\right)$ values which work are $\left(22,1\right),\left(23,3\right),\left(24,5\right),\ldots$, i..e, in general being $(22 + a, 1 + 2a)$ for $a$ being non-negative integers.  This keeps going up for $a = 16$ giving $\left(38,33\right)$, resulting in $162$ as stated by the question's author, hardyz009, in his/her comment to the original question.

Comment: how did u compute value of n and m.Because as per the explanation we compute n and m by dividing d and D with the gcd.
Hence n=4/2 and m=2/2

Comment: $hardz009, I have added a few more details to my answer, so I hope it explains it better for you and that you now understand it.

Comment: when you get the equation 84=(m−1)2−(n−1)4 but to calculate we just consider 
9n-1)=84 shouldnt the above equation be resolved to 2n-m=41, because we just cant break the equation in between to find values of n and m.

Comment: @hardz009 Yes, the equation can be simplified to $43 = 2n - m$.   However, note that $n$ and $m$ need to each be $\ge 1$, so this limits what values they can take.  Since 43 is an odd number and $2n$ is even, this means that $m$ must be odd, with the 1st value being 1.  This gives that $n = 22$.  For each increase in $n$, the right side increases by 2, so $m$ must increase by 2 (as it is being subtracted) to compensate to keep it an equation.  Thus, the sets of $\left(n, m\right)$ values which work are $\left(22, 1\right), \left(23, 3\right), \left(24, 5\right), \ldots$.

Comment: but then there has to be a way of calculating n and m with 43=2n-m the point you stated is valid but if it would have been a bigger number or lhs had been even then we wouldnt be doing a hit and trial to compute n and m.

Comment: @hardz009 There isn't any real trial & error involved.  Note that $43 = 2n - m$ can be rearranged to determine $m$ in terms of $n$ or the other way around.  For example, we have $m = 2n - 43$, or $n = \frac{m + 43}{2}$.  Thus, as I said, for $n = 22$, this gives from the $1$st equation that $m = 1$.  Next, for $n = 23$, this gives $m = 3$, and so on.  Perhaps I'm not clear on what you are not understanding, but I hope that if you carefully read what I've written and think about it, perhaps you will then determine what is going on. Also, note I've added most of my comment above into my answer.

Comment: @hardyz009 I'm sorry for misspelling your name several times, but I got the wrong version into my head.

Comment: i totally understand that the equation can reduced to n=m+43/2 and after that u take n=22  adn we arrived at n =22 by hit and tial only imagien if the euation was 
n=m+17653/3 then simply looking at it we can arrive at a number it will take some hit and trial to solve this equation and this is precisely what i wanted to undestand if the way we got to our first value of 22 is by hit and trial

Comment: @hardyz009 Thanks for your feedback. The way to get the first value is to consider the limitation that the values of $m$ and $n$ must be non-negative integers. Using your example of $n = \frac{m + 17653}{3}$, note that $17653$, when divided by $3$, leaves a remainder of $1$, so $m$ being $1$ will not work as $n$ will not be an integer. Instead, with $m$ being $2$, we get $n = \frac{2 + 17653}{3} = 5885$ as its first value. For each increase of $m$ by $3$, the value of $n$ increases by $1$. All other values of $m$ don't allow $n$ to be an integer and, thus, aren't an overlap of sequences.